# Convert joint probability distribution in Gaussian graphical model to the general form in the general graphical model?

Tags: normal-distribution, graphical-model

In the Gaussian graphical model, the joint distribution $p(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ of p continuous random variables is a multivariate Gaussian:
$$
p(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{p/2}|W^{-1}|^{1/2}}exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\textbf{x}-\mu)^TW(\textbf{x}-\mu)) ~~(1)
$$ 
where $W$ is the inverse-covariance matrix.

It is also known that in the undirected graphical model, the joint distribution $p(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ can be expressed as
$$
p(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \frac{1}{\text{normalizing constant}}\Pi_{i=1}^{p}\phi_i(x_i)\Pi_{(i,j)\in E}^{p}\phi_{i,j}(x_{i,j}) ~~ (2)
$$
where  $\phi_{i}$ and $\phi_{i,j}$ are called the non-negative potentials, and the set E constains the set of variables for the potential  $\phi_{i,j}$.

The question is how to expand the form in Equation (1) so that it has the form in Equation (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume it's enough to just expand the term in the exponential:
$$(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})=\sum_{i=1}^p (x_i-\mu_i)^2W_{ii}+2\sum_{i\neq j}(x_i-\mu_i)W_{ij}(x_j-\mu_j)$$
which yields

$$\phi_i(x_i)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_i)^2W_{ii}\right), \phi_{ij}(x_{i,j})=\exp\left(-(x_i-\mu_i)W_{ij}(x_j-\mu_j)\right)$$

You can also get rid of constant terms in these expressions caused by $\mu_{i,j}$, but I'm not sure if it is absolutely necessary.